# Adding azurepipelines-coverage.yml to the root of the repo doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, code-coverage

I wanted to set up an optional code coverage check for PRs in Azure DevOps pipeline. So I followed the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops#Coverage%20status,%20details%20and%20indicators) by adding an **azurepipelines-coverage.yml** file at the root of the repo that I am at, and literally copy-pasted the schema in the doc to check if it would work.

However, the pipeline doesn't show any checks/comments on the result for the code coverage check. According to [this website](https://www.benday.com/2023/01/10/enforce-code-coverage-as-part-of-pull-requests-in-azure-devops/#:%7E:text=Understanding%20Why%20the,why%20it%E2%80%99s%20failing.), it should create a comment at the bottom of the PR like this:

[image]

and was also expecting an additional optional check here:
[image]

but my pipeline doesn't have any additional checks. I know that the code coverage reports are successfully collected and published, because once the pipeline is done running, I do see content under the "Code Coverage" tab.

[image]

I'm wondering if this is because I'm not on the main branch to set this up? I've been testing in a PR I created that proposes to merge branchA to branchB, which neither are the main branch. Or would it be because this PR is in draft mode and hasn't been published?

Would love some feedback into how I can troubleshoot this!

[UPDATE]
This is the YML schema that I'm using:

```
 coverage:
    status:           # Code coverage status will be posted to pull requests based on targets defined below.
      comments: on    # Off by default. When on, details about coverage for each file changed will be posted as a pull request comment. 
    diff:           # Diff coverage is code coverage only for the lines changed in a pull request.
      target: 60%   # Set this to a desired percentage. Default is 70 percent
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, the pipeline doesn't show any checks/comments on the result for **the code coverage check**.

The comment by `Azure Pipelines Test Service` is in the pull request page, not the code coverage check in the pipeline.
[image: the pull request page]

[image: the code coverage check in the pipeline]

> I'm wondering if this is because I'm not on the main branch to set this up?

I tested the issue and found that if you want to create a pull request from branch1 to branch2, you just need to make sure the `azurepipelines-coverage.yml` file in the branch1. Then you’ll get a comment by `Azure Pipelines Test Service` in your pull request comment.

[image]

The content in `azurepipelines-coverage.yml`:

```
coverage:
  status:           # Code coverage status will be posted to pull requests based on targets defined below.
    comments: on    # Off by default. When on, details about coverage for each file changed will be posted as a pull request comment. 
    diff:           # Diff coverage is code coverage only for the lines changed in a pull request.
      target: 60%   # Set this to a desired percentage. Default is 70 percent
```

By the way, the official link should be [Configuring coverage settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops#configuring-coverage-settings), it seems that you add the wrong link in the question for the official doc. The two links are the same.

Update:

In branch2, you should set the Branch Policies.

Steps:

1. Open the branch policy page of branch

[image]

2. Add Build Validation. My build pipeline name is `unit test in pipeline`

[image]

3. Add the Status check. The check name is  `{build-pipeline-definition-name}/codecoverage`, and here is `unit test in pipeline/codecoverage` in the example.

[image]

Here is an official doc related to [Configure a branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pr-status-policy?view=azure-devops).

Update 2:

> The "Coverage status check queued for ...." appears when the build is
> running, but it later disappears.

I tested and found that if you didn't make change to your test code, the Coverage status check will disappear after the build is completed.

Example 1:

I only update some lines in the readme.md file. When the build is running, the Coverage status check queued. After the build is finished, in the comment, it shows `Coverage for changed lines cannot be determined. No testable code was changed.` Then the Coverage status  check disappears.

[image]

Example 2:

I updated the test code. The Coverage status check will be there, and the comment shows the details when build is finished.

[image]
[image]